# Variable throws initialization error after initializing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, initialization

I'm trying to make a Discord bot, one of its features is that it plays chess, at the start of the command, I read the JSON file, then check if it's `undefined` since I'll call a key from the object, so just in case it doesn't exist already, I'll create the data needed

Problem is, when I try to assign the data, it says I haven't initialized the variable, which is weird, because I did initialize it 3 lines before, `var`, `let` and `const` all throw the same error

Another thing is that outside the if statement, just above it, when console.logging it, it works perfectly, but when console.logging it inside the if statement, it throws that error

I honestly have no idea what's happening here, I can't think of anything that's causing this either, is this a NodeJS bug? I feel like it could be.

```
const games = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./lib/database/games/chess/chess_games.json"))
console.log(games, 'outside if statement') // Here it outputs just fine
if (games[interaction.guild.id] == undefined) {
    console.log(games, 'inside if statement') // Here is where it breaks
    games[interaction.guild.id] = {
        games: {},
        players: {},
        amount_of_games: 0
    }
    fs.writeFileSync("./lib/database/games/chess/chess_games.json", JSON.stringify(games, null, 2));
    const games = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./lib/database/games/chess/chess_games.json"))
}
```

This is the error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'games' before initialization
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\aschr\Dropbox\Coding\Javascript\entropic_bot\lib\database\bot\commands\chess.js:40:4)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aschr\Dropbox\Coding\Javascript\entropic_bot\index.js:44:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables with the same name.

Change the name of one of them

The second `games` is tried to be accessed instead of the first one because of hoisting. That's why you are getting the error

Comment: Do you mean the one in the object? (`games: {}`)

Comment: I mean `const games`

Comment: Oh that, lemme try that, although the line the error it outputs is the same line as the console.log

Comment: I'm so stupid you're right

Comment: Yes, because of hoisting. Change the sconce `const games` to `const anything` and it will work

Comment: When it said that I didn't realize it meant the second `games` as you mentioned

Comment: Yeah I just added it for good measure, although it's not really necessary so I'll keep it removed, thank you very much

Comment: I'll verify your answer as soon as it lets me, again, thank you lol, been struggling with this for about 15 minutes

Comment: 15 minutes, that probably felt like a lifetime

Comment: Definitely did, I honestly just had no idea what was wrong, I completely forgot I had that second `games` being initialized